# Does a multithreaded write-once, read-many need a volatile?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, static, volatile

Here is the scenario.  I've got a class that will be accessed by multiple threads (ASP.NET) that can benefit from storing a result in a write-once, read-many cache.  This cached object is the result of an operation that cannot be performed as part of a static initializer, but must wait for the first execution.  So I implement a simple null check as seen below.  I'm aware that if two threads hit this check at the same moment I will have ExpensiveCalculation calculated twice, but that isn't the end of the world.  My question is, do I need to worry about the static _cachedResult still being seen as null by other threads due to optimizations or other thread caching.  Once written, the object is only ever read so I don't think full-scale locking is needed.

```
public class Bippi
{

   private static ExpensiveCalculation _cachedResult;

   public int DoSomething(Something arg)
   {

      // calculate only once.  recalculating is not harmful, just wastes time.
      if (_cachedResult == null);
         _cachedResult = new ExpensiveCalculation(arg);


      // additional work with both arg and the results of the precalculated
      //    values of _cachedResult.A, _cachedResult.B, and _cachedResult.C
      int someResult = _cachedResult.A + _cachedResult.B + _cachedResult.C + arg.ChangableProp;
      return someResult;

   }

}

public class ExpensiveCalculation
{

   public int A { get; private set; }
   public int B { get; private set; }
   public int C { get; private set; }

   public ExpensiveCalculation(Something arg)
   {
      // arg is used to calculate A, B, and C
   }

}
```

Additional notes, this is in a .NET 4.0 application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, do I need to worry about the static _cachedResult still being seen as null by other threads due to optimizations or other thread caching.

Yes, you do.  That's one of the primary reasons `volatile` exists.

And it's worth mentioning that uncontested locks add an entirely negligible performance cost, so there's really no reason to just to just `lock` the null check and resource generation, as it's almost certainly not going to cause any performance problems, and makes the program much easier to reason about.

And the best solution is to avoid the question entirely and use a higher level of abstraction that is specifically designed to solve the exact problem that you have.  In this case, that means `Lazy`.  You can create a `Lazy` object that defines how to create your expensive resource, access it wherever you need the object, and the `Lazy` implementation becomes responsible for ensuring that the resource is created no more than once, and that it is properly exposed to the code asking for said resource, and that it is handled efficiently.

Comment: Cough. Yeah. Right. I have some code here we got 25% faster when we moved from multi to single threaded (and instead distributed batches to different cores). Happens all the "no cost" locks really did add up.

Comment: @TomTom Then your locks almost certainly weren't uncontested.  Your operations were all competing for the same scarce resources.  It also takes a lot of time to start up and tear down threads, in addition to synchronizing them.  There are all sorts of reasons for your problems, none of which is justification for not using a `lock` in the context described here.

Comment: Oh, they were consistent. Just some programmer thought they are free. They are not - and we had tons of ressources that got hit by at the end a single thread because in certain other scenarios where may be a second thread competing. The programmer made sure every possible path is duly locked. NIghtmare - and definitely not free. Locks have a cost. They had to be uncontested because in the scenario we measured it - there was exactly on thread running there ;)

Comment: @TomTom The cost is on the order of a couple of nanoseconds.  In the context described here, that can almost certainly be equated to zero.  In some other contexts, possibly not, but here, almost certainly yes.

Comment: @TomTom The cost for an uncontended lock (well in HotSpot, the CLR is generally less efficient here though, but not by that much), is basically the cost of a CAS. Worst case on x86 that's 100 cycles and draining the store buffers. Call it 300 cycles. That amounts to about 90ns on a modern CPU. That's damn close to "free". False sharing or actually contended locks are a much more likely explanation for a 25% performance increase..

Comment: In regards to `Lazy`, would the `Something arg` that will be captured by the closure when constructing `ExpensiveCalculation` now be held in memory unable to be garbage collected for the duration of the appliaction?  Or does the `Lazy` instance clean up itself after utilizing the factory function?

Comment: Actually, I cannot see how I can define the Lazy instance given it can only be created with the use of `Something arg`, which is only available within `DoSomething`.  Which means I will be null-checking the Lazy instance, which defeats the purpose of using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need not need volatile, you - especially - need a memory barrier so that the processor caches synchronize.

Comment: That is exactly what `volatile` will do; it will ensure the appropriate memory barriers are in place...

Comment: Except that volatile is the worst possible performance wise memory barrier.

Comment: How so?  And what are you comparing it to?

Comment: For my information, where would the `Thread.MemoryBarrier` need to be utilized.  Just after the assignment, or on the reads as well?

Comment: Read the second link (http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) - tons of good examples. THis is exactly one thing you can do optimization contrary to the volatile keyword.

Comment: @TomTom So first off, that's almost certainly premature optimization.  The described change, in the context of this question, is almost certainly going to be negligible, probably not even *measurable*.  That's describing a very different situation from what is described here.  It's describing a situation in with a variable is accessed many times from within a `lock` block, and only once outside of it.  Memory barriers are being applied inside the `lock` block needlessly, because the `lock` already applies those guarantees.  That isn't happening here at all, there is no `lock`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can altogether optimistically avoid locking, and yet avoid `volatile`  performance penalties.  You can test for nullability in a two-step fashion.

```
  object readonly _cachedResultLock = new object();

  ...

  if (_cachedResult == null)
  {
     lock(_cachedResultLock)
     {
         if (_cachedResult == null)
         {
             _cachedResult = new ExpensiveCalculation(arg);
         }
     }
   }
```

Here most of the time you will not reach lock and will not serialize access.  You may serialize access only on first access - but will guarantee that work is not wasted (though may cause another thread to wait a bit while first one finishes `ExpensiveCalculation`).